# Как правильно сделать выборку PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Помогите написать знание SQL:
дана таблица users вида - id, group_id

```
create temp table users(id bigserial, group_id bigint);

insert into users(group_id) values (1), (1), (1), (2), (1), (3);
```

В этой таблице, упорядоченой по ID (необходимо):

1. выделить непрерывные группы по group_id с учетом указанного порядка
   записей (их 4)
2. подсчитать количество записей в каждой группе
3. вычислить минимальный ID записи в группе

Написал так но не знаю правильно ли я понял вопрос :(

```
select distinct(group_id) from users
```

Comment: не знаете даже правильно ли поняли _свой_ вопрос? :-) да, такое бывает что другие понимают человека  лучше, чем сам он, по себе знаю :-) По первых, distinct это не фукция а ключевое слово, во вторых, там где нужно найти количество записей - должна быть агрегатная ф-ция COUNT(). Запрос напишу в след комментарии

Answer (score 0):

```
select temp.group_id as "группа", COUNT(temp.id) as "к-во записей", MIN(temp.id) as "минимальный id" 
from temp 
group by temp.group_id;
```

Замечания на будущее

1. distinct это не ф-ция а ключевое слово
2. нельзя требовать чтобы записи в базе следовали непрерывно, это
   абсурдное требование - вы же не можете контролировать в каком
   порядке пользователи БД введут данные, да и смысл данных от этого никак не поменяется

Comment: может быть вы следующий раз брату посоветуете самому написать? или это такая игра про испорченный телефон здесь появилась?

Comment: еще прикольно что вы фразу " в этой таблице, упорядоченой по ID необходимо:" тоже считаете вопросом :-))